# Nothing Happens when i call doPayment() method for Cashfree Payment

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment

I called the doPayment() method with proper parameter but nothing happens.
Token and "OK" status is generated.
here Is my code `

```
compositeDisposable.add(iCloudFunction.getToken(orderId,total_game_amount.getText().toString())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<CashFreeToken>()
        {
            @Override
            public void accept(CashFreeToken cashFreeToken) throws Exception {

                if(cashFreeToken.getStatus().equals("OK"))
                {
                    CFPaymentService.getCFPaymentServiceInstance().doAmazonPayment(CartActivity.this,dataSend,cashFreeToken.getCftoken(),"TEST");
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this,cashFreeToken.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this,""+throwable.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }));`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the **doAmazonPayment()** method instead of **doPayment()** method.

**doAmazonPayment()** method requires additional configurations to work.

For normal Payment Gateway, use **doPayment()** method.

Answer (score 0):

You are Calling the function on the background thread but it opens a Activity for payment which requires main thread.
Please Move the function out of the disposible function, it is safe to call it on main thread.